# Protobuf Deserialisation

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

We are using protobuf for few years now and it great for what we do.

However, lately we are experiencing few de-serialisation issue.

Previously deserialisation was done serially, now to speed up the process we have used all cores system can provide.

Scenario:

1. We are generating report, which includes 100 images.
2. Each image is a widget and each widget has its own data source.
3. We have more then one widget accessing same data(stored in protobuf).
4. Attached is a screenshot, which highlights 2 widgets begin deserialised.
5. Of them 1st is successfully deserialised.
6. 2nd one fails deserialisation with below attached error message

Note: 1st and 2nd deserialisation happens a few milliseconds apart.

Error:

> Context: 1 errors generating widgets. AnalysisTaskGlobalID:
>   d549f367-f42f-45fa-b230-f2839a6fefe6 Error: Exception of type
>   'ProtoBuf.ProtoException' was thrown. Stack:    at
>   ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.StartSubItem(ProtoReader reader) in
>   c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoReader.cs:line 599    at
>   ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key,
>   ProtoReader reader, Type type) in
>   c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoReader.cs:line 531    at
>   proto_2(Object , ProtoReader )    at
>   ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type
>   type, SerializationContext context) in
>   c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 506    at
>   ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize[T](Stream source) in
>   c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:line 69

We don't think its a multi threading issue!, as we tried synchronizing de-serialisation process.

However, when adding a sleep of 1000ms before de-serialisation, works most of the time!

Any thoughts on this, please let me know.

Comment: We are using Version 2 of protobuf

Comment: The type we are de-serialisating has 113000 bytes. Looks like size of object and use of multi threading is causing this issue. Is there any protobuf hints, I should be using?

Comment: It would make it a lot easier to to understand your question if you formatted the stack trace to be easier to read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This at in the end was not a protobuf error. Our application was not sufficiently synchronized.